# Miller effect in CMOS inverter

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, load

I have a doubt concerning the Miller effect. I found on more than one source the following situation:

[image]

where Cgd1 and Cgd2 are modeled as a capacitor connected to ground as a consequence of the Miller effect:

[image]

According to the Miller effect, shouldn't one model Cgd1 (and Cgd2) as two capacitors, one from Vin to GND and the other from Vout to GND, both with values equal to 2*Cgd1 (or Cgd2)? That's what I would do if I literally had to apply the Miller theorem on Cgd1 or Cgd2, given a gain of the inverter A=-1. Can someone explain me why only one capacitor from Vout to GND is used in the case of CMOS inverters?

Comment: Hello. What source were these copied from, and what supporting text went with them?

Comment: @TimWilliams the reference is "digital integrated circuits: a design perspective", Rabaey